# Mern stack bcrypt password works many times, and suddenly doesn't match

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, passwords, bcrypt

i have a strange problem and don't find the same so i search some help :) :
I make a mern stack social media, and first all is okay with register new user and logged in.
I'm on development of the app, so i login and logout a lot. And after a few times, i don't count, maybe 20 or 30, the password is not recognized, and i can't login with the account.
So i make a new user to continue my work, and the same thing happen after a few logins.

### Here is my userSchema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {isEmail} = require("validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

function validEmail(email) {
    if(!isEmail(email)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        pseudo: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minLength: 3,
            maxLength: 20,
            unique: true,
            trim: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true,
            unique: true,
            validate: validEmail
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            maxLength: 1024,
            minLength: 6
        },
        dimension: {
            type: String,
        },
        galaxy: {
            type: String,
        },
        picture: {
            type: String,
            default: "./uploads/profil/random-user.png"
        },
        bio: {
            type: String,
            maxLength: 1024
        },
        followers: {
            type: [String],
        },
        following: {
            type: [String]
        },
        likes: {
            type: [String]
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

// Play function before save into display: block
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
})

userSchema.statics.login = async function(email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({email});
    console.log(user)
    if(user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if(auth) {
            return user;
        } else {
            throw Error("Incorrect password");
        }
    }
    throw Error("Incorrect email");
}

const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = UserModel;
```

### And here the login function in my auth.controller.js:

```js
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.login(email, password);
        const token = createToken(user._id);
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            maxAge: maxAge, sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
         })
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id })

    }
    catch (err) {
        const errors = signInErrors(err);
        res.status(200).json({ errors });
        // console.log(err)
    }
}
```

It's my first project with back-end side, and i follow a tutorial from 2020 to make it, so maybe there is new best practices to do it now. But it seems very strange that it works fine with new user, and not after some connections. I hope someone have an idea to try to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I find this and try, seems to work for me after 2 days, with adding a condition on the pre hook like this:

```js
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
    if(!this.isModified("password")) {
        return next()
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);
    next();
})
```

Hope it help someone